# Creating a program which counts words number in a row of a text file (Python)

Tags: python, input, output, counter

I am trying to create a program which takes an input file, counts the number of words in each row and writes a string of that certain number in another output file. I managed to develope this code:

```
in_file = "our_input.txt"
out_file = "output.txt"
f=open(in_file)
g=open(out_file,"w")
for line in f:
    if line == "\n":
        g.write("0\n")
    else:
        g.write(str(line.count(" ")+1)+"\n")
```

now, this works well, but the problem is that it works for only a certain amount of lines. If my input file has 8000 lines, it will display only the first 6800. If it has 6000, than will be displayed (all numbers are rounded, right).
I tried creating another program, which splits each line to a list, and then counting the length of it, but the problem remains just the same.
Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close each file after you're done with it. The safest way to do this is by using the `with` statement:

```
with open(in_file) as f, open(out_file,"w") as g:
    for line in f:
        if line == "\n":
            g.write("0\n")
        else:
            g.write(str(line.count(" ")+1)+"\n")
```

When reaching the end of a `with` block, all files you opened in the `with` line will be closed.

The reason for the behavior you see is that for performance reasons, reading and writing to/from files is *buffered*. Because of the way hard drives are constructed, data is read/written in blocks rather than in individual bytes - so even if you attempt to read/write a single byte, you have to read/write an entire block. Therefore, most programming languages' built-in file IO functions actually read (at least) one block at a time into memory and feed you data from that in-memory block until it needs to read another block. Similarly, writing is performed by actually writing into a memory block first, and only writing the block to disk when it is full. If you don't close the file writer, whatever is in the last in-memory block won't be written.

Comment: I have tried to use the with function, in a different structure that you offered, but nothing has been changed.

Comment: well, I tried that again by simply copying your code and it worked. First of all - thanks a lot, and second, do you have the slightest idea why would that code work just for the first 6880 lines out of 8381? I just can't see the problem. even with or without closing the file...

Comment: See my update. Based on the sizes of your lines and Python's buffer sizes, it just so happened that the last 1501 lines were left in the buffer. Try with a file that contains shorter or longer lines, and you should see a different number of omitted lines.